# Ruby equivalent of Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() in 64 bits

Tags: java, ruby, time

I am using Ruby to generate a 64 bit timestamp similar to Java. I went through [Class:Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html) and it says time could use 63 bit integer. I thought I could use:

```
Time.now.to_f * 1000
```

but I am worried about losing precision due to the floating point conversion. Can I simply get the 64 bit timestamp (millis since epoch) as in Java in ruby, as precise as possible?

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

I need to use the timestamp as unique ID in a database, so I would like to keep time-related collisions from minimum to non-existent.

Comment: Note that your Java code is a pretty complex way of calling `System.currentTimeMillis`. (And it's still *really* not a good way of creating a unique timestamp.)

Comment: Okay, what is the best way to get 64 bit timestamp in ruby or Java? I need uniqueness (not really, I can handle small collisions.) to some extent, but what I really need is the ability to sort based on this 64 bit number.

Comment: To get a *unique* timestamp, I wouldn't use the system clock to start with. Just use a sequence in the database, with a way of reserving "chunks" if you need to be able to predict IDs on the client side.

Comment: My application uses NoSQL, I can't really use an atomic counter, as it is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Then use a GUID. (Using an atomic counter really doesn't *have* to be expensive if a client can reserve some part of the ID space and do everything locally for a long-running session.)

Comment: Even if the timestamp is negative in 293 million years time it will take another 292 million years for a 64-bit timestamp to repeat.  Is that really a problem for you given there wasn't even land animals or trees the last time a 64-bit timestamp would have had the current time.

Comment: No, when I generate two timestamps consecutively in Ruby, they could overlap due to floating point conversion when they could be precise if they were 64-bit integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added comments suggesting this really isn't what you should be doing anyway, but I *really* don't think you need to worry about losing precision in any meaningful way. The Ruby documentation states that the value is stored down to the nanosecond. Converting it to a floating point number may lose the last few digits, but it's not going to be significant at the millisecond level - you really don't care if the value round up or down a bit, after all... you're already relying on only creating a single entry per millisecond.

An alternative approach would be to use `to_i` and `nsec`: multiply the result of `to_i` by 1000, divide the result of `nsec` by 1000000, and add the two together. That will get you the number of milliseconds using only integer arithmetic.

Comment: I've decided to take the nsec route. Thanks a lot! I am marking this as answer. I was expecting there was a magical way of just getting the timestamp (to whatever degree of accuracy that the system will allow) in Ruby.

Basically I need the ability to sort based on this timestamp. Several of my web servers will generate timestamps and upload to a db (distributed hash table.) The hashtable is <Int64, Set> which stores data in sorted order. The "Set" cannot be too large. I want to answer queries like get recent x entries.

Answer (score 2):

The time is signed long in Java so it is 63-bit also.

So you are worried that in this year you will get an overflow?  Personally, I don't think anyone will be using Java by then. In fact it's likely we will be extinct/evolved by then as well.

```
  System.out.println("Overflow at " + new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
```

prints

```
  Overflow at Sun Aug 17 08:12:55 CET 292278994
```

Note: 292 million years ago was *before* the dinosaurs ruled the earth.

---

If you are concerned about the loss of accuracy of converting a nano-second time stamp to double you can calculate what that error is

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000000L;
double error_f = Math.ulp((float) now);
double error = Math.ulp((double) now);

System.out.println("The error for a nano-second timestamp using a double "
        + now + " is " + error + " and float is " + error_f);
```

prints

```
The error for a nano-second timestamp using a double 1378970569656000000 is 256.0 and float is 1.37438953472E11
```

This means the error for converting to `double` is up to half of this which is 128 ns, for converting to float, the error is also half the ulp, which is 68 seconds, which is quite high.

Comment: I am not worried about overflow at all. I am worried with Ruby's "to_f" conversion we'd lose precision from 64 bit. Is that not a correct statement?

Comment: @foobarometer Updated my answer for converting to float and a double. In short, there is almost never a good time to use float.

Comment: Ruby doc doesn't allow another option besides the nsec to_i option Jon Skeet suggests. Thank you for your answer, it gave me a perspective on how much collisions I might have.